# Minimize room size for social distancing

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have to minimize the area of a squared room to keep a 2-meter distance between n people. How could I model the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach would be

- Introduce a variable `p_x` and `p_y` for each person `p`. This gives the position of the person in the room.
- minimize `(max(p_x) - min(p_x)) * (max(p_y) - min(p_y))` (the area). For a squared room you would have to minimize `max((max(p_x) - min(p_x)), (max(p_y) - min(p_y))) ^ 2`.
- the constraint is that for any two persons `p1` and `p2` the distance between `(p1_x, p1_y)` and `(p2_x, p2_y)` is at least 2 metres.

Note that what you are trying to do is related to "circle packing" or "disk packing": each person can be represented as a disk with radius 1m and you are looking for the smallest rectangle into which all disks can be packed. You may check out this problem and how it is modeled/solved.